# StringConcatFactory problem in try catch block with recursion

Tags: java

I'm working on a Java CPU benchmark that tests the number of recursive calls for a method that returns the sum of all prime numbers, from a variable called `start`. This is how my method looks like:

```
private long recursive(long start, int size, int counter) {
    long temp = findNextPrime(start);
    if (temp > size) return 0;
    try {
        return temp + recursive(temp, size, counter + 1);
    } catch (StackOverflowError e) {
        System.out.println("Reached nr " + start + "/" + size + " after " + counter + " calls.");
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I am looking for a `StackOverflowError` exception and want to output the last sum calculated before reaching that exception. Everything seems to work fine from a logical point of view, when I'm using a smaller value for `size`. The prime numbers are picked up correctly, and the sum is calculated correctly.

The problem is for greater values of `size`, where the exception is actually thrown. When I don't output anything in the `catch()` section (I comment the `System.out.println()` line), everything seems to be okay, but when I just let the print line as it is, I receive the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class java.lang.invoke.StringConcatFactory
at java.base/java.lang.invoke.DirectMethodHandle.shouldBeInitialized(DirectMethodHandle.java:347)
    at java.base/java.lang.invoke.DirectMethodHandle.preparedLambdaForm(DirectMethodHandle.java:193)
    at java.base/java.lang.invoke.DirectMethodHandle.preparedLambdaForm(DirectMethodHandle.java:210)
    at java.base/java.lang.invoke.DirectMethodHandle.make(DirectMethodHandle.java:105)
    at java.base/java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.getDirectMethodCommon(MethodHandles.java:2322)
    at java.base/java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.getDirectMethodNoSecurityManager(MethodHandles.java:2278)
    at java.base/java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.getDirectMethodForConstant(MethodHandles.java:2520)
    at java.base/java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.linkMethodHandleConstant(MethodHandles.java:2466)
    at java.base/java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.linkMethodHandleConstant(MethodHandleNatives.java:592)
    at benchmark.cpu.CPURecursionLoopUnrollingBenchmark.recursive(CPURecursionLoopUnrollingBenchmark.java:61)
    at benchmark.cpu.CPURecursionLoopUnrollingBenchmark.recursive(CPURecursionLoopUnrollingBenchmark.java:59)
```

The last line repeats itself a huge number of times. **Line 59** in my code represents the `return` statement from the `try` block (`return temp + ...`). I am using IntelliJ with a Java 11 SDK and never ever met this error before.

It is obviously a concatenation problem, because if I'm just outputting a simple string (without any `+` operators), everything seems to work fine. The string concatenation **works** outside this method.

I am not going to also display the other method (`findNextPrime()`), because I feel like wasting too much space and making the question more complex as it already is. If you need more details, please leave a comment and I will surely add the other method, too (or what you're asking for).

Comment: I think it crashes because it tries to initialise `StringConcatFactory`, which involves creating a new stack frame, but the stack already overflowed... There's probably some implementation differences between JDK 11 and whatever you were using before. In any case, **you are not supposed to catch** `StackOverflowError`s.

Comment: This looks like an error where the compiler, JDK, and runtime are not all running at the same version of Java.